# Office js addin login issue in IE Unable to get property 'registerForEvent' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angular, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

Hi i am using https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers office helper for office outlook addin login.
When I use OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog() throw this error and IE doesn't close de dialog
Example:

```
Office.initialize = function (){

        if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) return;
        var authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();
         authenticator.endpoints.add("endpoint", {
            baseUrl: "BASE_URL",
            authorizeUrl: "Authorize_URL",
            clientId: "Client_id",
            responseType: "token",
            scope: "user",
            redirectUrl: "redirect",
        });

        var t = authenticator.authenticate("endpoint");
        t.then(function(token){

            console.log("logged");
        })
        .catch(function(error){

            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

And its working all other browser (chrome, edge) and native outlook client. Please help me to find the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar bug here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers/issues/29 for office-js-helpers. Please watch on it.

Thanks